# How to use Get Record to lookup a related record on another object when I don't have the schema Entity Name - Just the LogicalName

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate

All,

I am building a Power Flow.  I am returning an object that has a relationship to another entity.

I want to get some values from the related entity.

I am attemping to use the "Get Record" connector.  The returning object returns just the logicalEntityName (in this case "opportunities") but Get Record wants an Entity Name that is the Schema Name ("Working Opportunities").

Big Question:  What's the secret to use CDS to get information from a related record in another object?

Little Question:  How do I do get the Schema Name?

Comment: Do you have follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

The logical name will be the same as schema name except some casing difference, ie schema name will have camel casing (first letter of first/second word with capitals, you can notice it clearly in custom entity which will have publisher prefix like `new_entityname`) and logical name will have pascal casing (all lower case).

You can find the details in XrmToolBox metadata browser or in Solution.

In the below snip, **(*Logical*) Name = Opportunity** and **Schema Name = Opportunity**, also Display Name can be anything and can be changed anytime.

[image]

Regarding the related entities, you should use `List Records: GetItems_V2` and you can use filter by passing parent record to get related child records. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataservice/#list-records)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share flow screenshot and response to help you with your requirement?

As suggested by Arun you could use List Record and filter query to pass parent record id which will be available from dynamic content.

see below link.
https://crmkeeper.com/2019/08/31/cds-list-records-filter-query-using-flow/

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful